# Am I forgetting a factor of $2$ in calculating the area of $S=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3 | x^2+y^2+z^2=25, 2x^2+y^2\leq 25\}$?

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, surfaces

Am I forgetting a $2$ in calculating the area of $S=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3 | x^2+y^2+z^2=25, 2x^2+y^2\leq 25\}$?

Here is my solution: $$z^2+y^2+z^2 = 25 \Rightarrow z = \pm\sqrt{25-x^2-y^2}$$
We can now consider only the top-half of the sphere and double the area at the end. Now I need to calculate
$$||T_x\times T_y||=||\begin{vmatrix}\vec{i} & \vec{j} & \vec{k} \newline 1 & 0 & \frac{-x}{\sqrt{25-x^2-y^2}} \newline 0 & 1 & \frac{-y}{\sqrt{25-x^2-y^2}}\end{vmatrix}|| = \sqrt{\frac{25}{25-x^2-y^2}}$$

Finally, I need to calculate
$$\int\int_D\sqrt{\frac{25}{25-x^2-y^2}}\text{d}x\text{d}y$$
To do this, I transform into polar coordinates:
$$\begin{cases}x=5r\cos(t) \\ y=5r\sin(t)\end{cases}, r\in[0,1], t\in[0,2\pi]$$
From $2x^2+y^2\leq 25 \Rightarrow 25r^2\cos^2(t)+25r^2\leq 25 \Rightarrow r \leq\sqrt{\frac{1}{\cos^2(t)+1}}$.

Thus, the final integral is
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{\frac{1}{\cos^2(t)+1}}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}\cdot 25r\ \text{d}r\text{d}t$$

However, even after doubling the result of this, my result ends up being half of that given in my book (which is $100\pi$), and I am unable to see where I am missing a $2$ along the way. Any help here is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your answer $(50\pi)$ is correct, and you don't especially need calculus to see why. First note that $100\pi$ is the area of the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=25$, too much to be the area you want, which is clearly a subset of the sphere.

The intersection of the sphere and ellipse is a pair of perpendicular planes,

$$\begin{cases}x^2+y^2+z^2=25\\2x^2+y^2=25\end{cases} \implies z^2=x^2$$

and these planes slice the sphere into $4$ uniform pieces of equal area, and $2$ of these would make up $50\pi$.

---

Let's confirm with another integral. In spherical coordinates $(x,y,z)=(\rho\cos\theta\sin\varphi,\rho\sin\theta\sin\varphi,\rho\cos\varphi)$, restricting $z\ge|x| \iff |\varphi|\le\dfrac\pi4$, the intersection above gives the equation

$$\rho^2 \cos^2\varphi = \rho^2 \cos^2\theta \sin^2\varphi \implies \tan \varphi = \pm \sec \theta$$

so that by symmetry, the area is given by

$$A = 2 \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\arctan(\sec\theta)} 25\sin\varphi \, d\varphi \, d\theta$$

Now recall that $\cos\left(\arctan x\right)=\dfrac1{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$, and take advantage of symmetry to reduce the integral to

$$\begin{align*}
A &= 50 \int_0^{2\pi} \left(1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\sec^2\theta}}\right) \, d\theta \\
&= 100\pi - 50 \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{1+\sec^2\theta}} \\
&= 100\pi - 50\times4 \int_0^\tfrac\pi2 \frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{1+\sec^2\theta}} \\
&= 100\pi - 200 \underbrace{\int_1^\infty \frac{du}{u\sqrt{u^4-1}}}_{=\tfrac\pi4} & u=\sec t \\
&= \boxed{50\pi}
\end{align*}$$

The indicated integral is elementary:

$$\int \frac{du}{u \sqrt{u^4-1}} \stackrel{v^2=u^4-1}= \frac12 \int \frac{v}{\lvert v\rvert \left(v^2+1\right)} \, dv$$